# What is the complexity (in the Lévy hierarchy) of the axiom $\text{I0}$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

I have read the Wikipedia article on [the Lévy hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy). It mentions a few large cardinal axioms, but it does not mention any of the [rank-into-rank axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-into-rank). So I have the following questions:

1. what is the complexity (in the Lévy hierarchy) of the axiom $\text{I0}$?
2. Is there any source (a book/paper) that provides the axiom $\text{I0}$ written in some formal language (similar to how [this article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) provides the descriptions of the axioms of ZF)?
3. What can be an example of a formal language that allows to formulate the axiom $\text{I0}$?

Comment: The "naive" definition of I0 isn't even in the Levy hierarchy at all, since it requires us to quantify over elementary embeddings between particular classes: it's $\Sigma^{\color{red}{1}}_1(V)$. Now admittedly we can usually "set-ify" such large cardinal definitions with work (e.g. measurability: "There is a nontrivial elementary $j:V\rightarrow M$ with $crit(j)=\kappa$" is $\Sigma^1_1(V)$ but equivalent to "There is a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$" which is merely $\Sigma_2$), but I don't see how to do that with $I0$. Maybe someone else can chime in here ...

Comment: As it turns out, we *can* "set-ify" the definition of $I0$ - see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4515171/28111. (I think Asaf will post an answer here, so I'm keeping this as a comment.)