# The meaning of the $\Sigma_n^m(V)$ notation

Tags: notation, set-theory

I am puzzled by [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4502338/what-is-the-complexity-in-the-l%C3%A9vy-hierarchy-of-the-axiom-texti0#comment9450563_4502338) to my previous question. How can a set of axioms belong to the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy), but not to the [Lévy hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy)?

Does the $\Sigma^m_n(V)$ notation imply the arithmetical hierarchy with the additional assumption that a formula (in the language of first-order arithmetic) contains one additional symbol ($V$) that refers to the von Neumann universe? If no, what does this notation mean?

And why isn't the $\Sigma^m_n(V)$ notation interchangeable with something like $\Sigma_n^T$ (in the Lévy hierarchy), where $T$ is a first-order set theory whose universe of discourse consists of classes (such as Morse–Kelley set theory)? The language of $T$ allows to define the class $V$, so where is the obstacle?

Comment: No, this refers to higher-order formulas (with parameters in $V$) that begin with an existential $m$-th order quantifier. Second-order variables range over classes both proper and improper, and so on. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indescribable_cardinal for more context.

Comment: Is there any source (a book/paper) where I can read the explanation of what the $\Sigma_n^m(\ldots)$ notation means?

Comment: The two books cited in the wiki article, Drake and Kanamori, are standard and cover this well. Jech (Set Theory, 3rd millenium edition, in the short section "Indescribability" (p. 295-299)) defines the notion with a few paragraphs and immediately proves a few important theorems. I'd recomment Drake's  (Set Theory: An Introduction to Large Cardinals). He spends a lot of time on (in)describability and explores "small large cardinals" in more depth than the later monographs. Proofs are thorough, very little handwaving or assertions that some readers/students don't "get" without more explanation.

Comment: @BrianO: My question is not about the notion of (in)describability. I checked all these sources: they explain the meaning of $\Sigma_n^m$, but I cannot seem to find an explanation of the purpose of _the parenthesized entity_ after $\Sigma_n^m$.

Comment: Ah ok now I get what you're asking, sorry! .The sentence “there is an inaccessible“ says that there’s an element *in* $V$ with such and such first order property.  it’s $\Sigma^{0}_{2}(V)$. Of the rank-into-rank axioms, I0 and I2 assert that a certain proper class $j$ exists, and it’s an elementary embedding of a proper class universe ($L(V_{\lambda+1})$ and $V$ respectively) such that $\lambda, j$  have some first order property. Writing them in the obvious way gives $\Sigma^1_k(V)$ sentences — you need a 2nd order existential quantifier to express them.  1/2

Comment: 2/2 Axiom I0 seems to be more precisely $\Sigma^1_1(L(V_{\lambda+1}))$. The other rank-into-rank axioms seem to talk only about sets. Perhaps you should ask @NoahSchweber to clarify that in the comments to your original question, allowing that he himself asked for clarification by others.