# A countable language to express the theory of ZFC + “there exists a proper class of $\text{I0}$ cardinals”

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Does there exist a countable language (i.e. a language with countably many symbols) $\mathcal{L}$ of set theory such that the theory ZFC + "there exists a proper class of $\text{I0}$ cardinals" can be expressed by countably many statements in $\mathcal{L}$, assuming that the length of each statement is finite? If no, why? If yes, what can be an example of such language?

Comment: What's wrong with $\mathsf{NBG}$? All that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is missing (in terms of being able to directly talk about I0) is the ability to refer to proper classes. I believe you're overthinking this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can phrase $\rm I0$ in $\sf ZFC$, so you can just say that for every $\alpha$ there is $\kappa>\alpha$ which is the critical point of an $\rm I0$ embedding.

The reference here is:

> *Woodin, W. Hugh*, [**Suitable extender models. II: Beyond $\omega$-huge**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S021906131100102X), J. Math. Log. 11, No. 2, 115-436 (2011). [ZBL1248.03069](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1248.03069).

And the general fact is that if $\alpha$ is $\Sigma_2$-reflective, and there is an embedding $j\colon L_\alpha(V_{\lambda+1})\to L_\alpha(V_{\lambda+1})$, then we can derive an extender and define the ultrapower embedding that will witness $\rm I0$.

Comment: With regards to Gabe Goldberg that directed to these facts.

Comment: Nice - I had a hunch that was the case, but I didn't know a source for it! Note that this also answers [the OP's earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4502338/what-is-the-complexity-in-the-l%c3%a9vy-hierarchy-of-the-axiom-texti0).